# Is there a way to refresh/update the hyperlink in a shape when the hyperlink is clicked?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, shapes

I have shapes in a diagram that represent processes in a data flow; the shapes are hyperlinked to process definitions located in another tab based on the text in the shape and shape name (e.g. shape named "Control ##" with text "ABC" links to a tab where ABC process is defined).  Is there a way to automatcially update the hyperlink in that shape if I change the text in the shape to be "XYZ" - i.e. I want the hyperlink to then go to the "XYZ" definition?  I tried SheetFollowHyperlink event procedure but nothing seems to happen.  Code i have so far is below:

```
Sub AssignHyperlink()

Dim CallerShapeName As String
CallerShapeName = Application.Caller

With ActiveSheet
    Dim CallerShape As Shape
    Set CallerShape = .Shapes(CallerShapeName)

    Dim RowVar As Integer

    Err.Number = 0
    On Error Resume Next

    If InStr(CallerShapeName, "Control") = 1 Then

        RowVar = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Match(.Range("C2").Value & CallerShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, _
            Sheets("Control Point Log").Range("A1:A700"), 0)

        If (Err.Number = 1004) Then
            MsgBox "No match found for this shape text in the Control Point Log"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=CallerShape, _
        Address:=ActiveWorkbook.Name & "#" & "'Control Point Log'!$C$" & RowVar

    Else

        RowVar = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Match(.Range("C2").Value & CallerShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, _
            Sheets("Data Flow Glossary").Range("A1:A700"), 0)

        If (Err.Number = 1004) Then
            MsgBox "No match found for this shape text in the Data Flow Glossary"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=CallerShape, _
        Address:=ActiveWorkbook.Name & "#" & "'Data Flow Glossary'!$C$" & RowVar

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When the shape is clicked, why not retrieve the text of the shape and use that to directly navigate to the relevant worksheet? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am using the text of the shape to link, but when I change the text, it doesn't re- link the shape using the new text.

Comment: Which way you define destination of the hyperling? are they simply 'tabs' (sheets) name or you use 'named ranges' within your workbook?

Comment: One more question- you said 'shapes in a diagram'- is it a `SmartArt` object of simply few shapes which are composed in diagram type layout?

Comment: The destination is a range (cell) in the tab control point or data flow glossary.  The code looks for the row that contains the shape text, column is always C.

Comment: the shapes are flow chart shapes.

Comment: yes, ok, but which way you created it, using standard built-in SmartArt object? it's important for workaround I'd like to propose you

Comment: No, they were not created using smart art

Comment: anyway, if it's SmartArt object I have no idea, if you have few simple shapes chart layout you could change `hyperlinks` to `onAction` feature of shape... than one (for all shapes) simple macro would be called when you click the shape. That macro could navigate wherever you want within your workbook

Comment: Give me info  if you are interested in that kind of answer and support.

Comment: So the macro i have wouldn't be assigned to the shapes? I've never used onaction, so not sure how it works. I would like to try it, What kind of info do you need?

Comment: right-click on the shape gives you `on Action` option (or something similar as I don't use English version of Excel I can't check it). You could set macro then which will be fired (however, you need to delete hyperlink of that shape before running). Using that macro you can navigate... I you have any problem you can either leave a comment here or start new question...

Comment: Thank you.  I will remove hyperlinks and try on action to run the macro and see if that works.

Comment: When I right click on the shape I don't see on action as an option, just assign macro.  I'm using excel 2007

Comment: That's the option you should use...

Comment: I'm confused...that is what I am doing already

Comment: i'll show you in few minutes my logic in answer

Answer (score 1):

**1st.** I assume that your goal is to navigate to range within your workbook after you click on the shape

**2nd.** The range to navigate to is named range.

**3rd.** The range to navigate equals the text in the shape.

My proposal is to use `onAction` trigger of shape (`assign macro` when right click of the shape)

**4rd.** We need the following procedure- one for all shapes.

```
Sub Hyperlink_Workaround()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim curHL As String
        curHL = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text

    'which way do you define destination?
    'this way you go to named range

    Application.Goto Range(curHL), True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "There is no range like " & curHL
End Sub
```

**5th.** Test, having the following shapes on the sheet with above macro assigned, after click on any of the shape we would move to either ABC or DEF Range within our workbook.
[image]

**6th.** I added handler for situation when you try to navigate to the range that doesn't exist.

Comment: + 1 Exactly my point. OP was late in answering else I would have pasted almost the same code yesterday LOL.

Comment: Thank you, that does work but I have a large number of cells that I would have to name for that to work (over 225).  Is there any other workaround you can suggest for the hyperlink? If I check for a hyperlink fist and replace it? Would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure if I then get you right... you've written: 'I want the hyperlink to then go to the "XYZ" definition?' so, it's mean that you have that definition somewhere. So, where and in which way do you store information that XYZ should open something like  Sheet("Foo").Range("A100")...

Comment: I "define" XYZ in another sheet but didn't name the range XYZ, the cell value is XYZ.  Does that help?  The "definition" is a cell that explains what XYZ means for new users.

Comment: Now I get it. However, I was just thinking if I could propose you anything interesting but I didn't find any good solution. In your situation only `Range.Find` method seems to be working but then you have to run it for each sheet separately (consider it if you don't have too much sheets). The other option would be to have a matrix/array of 'XYZs' >> 'XYZ's destination' which could be very useful. Finally, I find `Range.Name` appropriate solution in your situation...

Comment: So if I did something like:     sheets("control Point Log").range("c1:c700").select.    range.name = "search_field" before     application.goto range("search_field") it might work?

Comment: yes, there you have named ranges, in my opinion quite good and simple option for you

Comment: If you have any range named `XYZ`, if you then put this `XYZ` as a text in the shape (like on pictures above) then code in my answer will simply work. However, if you name your range `XYZ_ABC` then you need to put the same string in shape, not `XYZ ABC` which is different. If you can't figure it out based on my answer then I would need to see your code. The best option for that could be to start new question presenting what you have.

Comment: Thank you.  I did get your code to work, but only for individual cell ranges, it didn't work for me when I tried a multiple cell range. I will think about how best to approach the problem since I don't want to name 200+ cells...